# Marshalling XML for http request

Tags: java, xml, http, soap, marshalling

I am trying to send an HTTP request from a Java Backend endpoint (App Engine)

when I post the following data from Postman I get a result,

```
POST
URL: https://my.url.here/example.asmx

Headers: 
Content-Type     text/xml

Body: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetResidents xmlns="http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData">
<UserName>myUser</UserName>
<Password>myPass</Password>
<ServerName>myServer</ServerName>
<Database>npks_test</Database>
<Platform>Sql Server</Platform>
<InterfaceEntity>Itex Payments</InterfaceEntity>
<InterfaceLicense>LICENSEHERE</InterfaceLicense>
<MoveOut1>04/01/2013</MoveOut1>
</GetResidents>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but when I try this: from my code it returns as 200 but with no data, so it must mean I either missed something.  or I'm doing something completely wrong.

I have done other HTTP requests so I think the problem is somewhere in the marshaller anyone has any ideas what I have done wrong

This is the Http request method

```
    public static Response getResidentsPerProperty(String property) throws IOException, JAXBException {
    SoapGetResidents soapGetResidents = new SoapGetResidents();
    GetResidents getResidents = new GetResidents();
    getResidents.setXmlns("http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData");
    getResidents.setUserName("myUser");
    getResidents.setPassword("myPass");
    getResidents.setServerName("myServer");
    getResidents.setDatabase("npks_test");
    getResidents.setPlatform("Sql Server");
    getResidents.setInterfaceEntity("Itex Payments");
    getResidents.setInterfaceLicense(INTERFACE_LICENSE);
    getResidents.setMoveOut1("04/01/2013");
    soapGetResidents.setGetResidents(getResidents);
    URL url = new URL(URL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(1000000);
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SoapGetResidents.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(soapGetResidents, os);
    os.flush();
    connection.getResponseCode();
    Response response = new Response (connection.getResponseMessage());
    connection.disconnect();
    return response;
}
```

Response Class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Response{

private    String response;

public Response(String response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public String getResponse() {
    return response;
}

@XmlElement
public void setResponse(String response) {
    this.response = response;
}
}



    public static Response getResidentsPerProperty(String property) throws IOException, JAXBException {
    SoapGetResidents soapGetResidents = new SoapGetResidents();
    GetResidents getResidents = new GetResidents();
    getResidents.setXmlns("http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData");
    getResidents.setUserName("itexITF");
    getResidents.setPassword("Password1");
    getResidents.setServerName("vNSQL8T_2K8R2");
    getResidents.setDatabase("npks_test");
    getResidents.setPlatform("Sql Server");
    getResidents.setInterfaceEntity("Itex Payments");
    getResidents.setInterfaceLicense(INTERFACE_LICENSE);
    getResidents.setMoveOut1("04/01/2013");
    soapGetResidents.setGetResidents(getResidents);
    URL url = new URL(URL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(1000000);
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SoapGetResidents.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(soapGetResidents, os);
    os.flush();
    connection.getResponseCode();
    Response response = new Response (connection.getResponseMessage());
    connection.disconnect();
    return response;
}
```

GetResidents Class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class GetResidents
{
private String InterfaceLicense;

private String MoveOut1;

private String InterfaceEntity;

private String Database;

private String Password;

private String UserName;

private String xmlns;

private String ServerName;

private String Platform;

public String getInterfaceLicense ()
{
    return InterfaceLicense;
}

@XmlElement
public void setInterfaceLicense (String InterfaceLicense)
{
    this.InterfaceLicense = InterfaceLicense;
}

public String getMoveOut1 ()
{
    return MoveOut1;
}
@XmlElement
public void setMoveOut1 (String MoveOut1)
{
    this.MoveOut1 = MoveOut1;
}

public String getInterfaceEntity ()
{
    return InterfaceEntity;
}

@XmlElement
public void setInterfaceEntity (String InterfaceEntity)
{
    this.InterfaceEntity = InterfaceEntity;
}

public String getDatabase ()
{
    return Database;
}

@XmlElement
public void setDatabase (String Database)
{
    this.Database = Database;
}

public String getPassword ()
{
    return Password;
}

@XmlElement
public void setPassword (String Password)
{
    this.Password = Password;
}

public String getUserName ()
{
    return UserName;
}

@XmlElement
public void setUserName (String UserName)
{
    this.UserName = UserName;
}

public String getXmlns ()
{
    return xmlns;
}

@XmlElement
public void setXmlns (String xmlns)
{
    this.xmlns = xmlns;
}

public String getServerName ()
{
    return ServerName;
}

@XmlElement
public void setServerName (String ServerName)
{
    this.ServerName = ServerName;
}

public String getPlatform ()
{
    return Platform;
}

@XmlElement
public void setPlatform (String Platform)
{
    this.Platform = Platform;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [InterfaceLicense = "+InterfaceLicense+", MoveOut1 = "+MoveOut1+", InterfaceEntity = "+InterfaceEntity+", Database = "+Database+", Password = "+Password+",  UserName = "+UserName+", xmlns = "+xmlns+", ServerName = "+ServerName+", Platform = "+Platform+"]";
}
}
```